# WiFi USB adapter with Linux drivers not detected on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

[This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07V4R3QHW) product.
[This](https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux) repo.

lsusb without the adapter plugged in:

```
 mmkstarr@sqirly-syllybus:~/computers$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 25a7:fa23  
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:58c2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1fd2:5001  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1058:25a2 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05e3:0616 Genesys Logic, Inc. hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0cf3:e009 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsusb` with the adapter plugged in:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 25a7:fa23  
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:58c2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1fd2:5001  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1058:25a2 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05e3:0616 Genesys Logic, Inc. hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0cf3:e009 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So nothing changes when it is plugged in, meaning it isn't detected.

I followed the instructions for installing the supported module, inlcuding `modprobe`, and here are the results of `lsmod`:

```
lsmod less
Module                  Size  Used by
rtl8812au            1351680  0
```

etc.

This is the name of the module supplied with the adapter on the CD and at the GitHub repo. I've tried installing straight from the CD but some makefiles aren't configured correctly or something, and the repo at GitHub works but in the end the adapter isn't detected anyway.

```
$ uname -a
Linux sqirly-syllybus 5.3.0-26-generic #28~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 16:40:14 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: DId you try this repo: https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959

Comment: Thanks @DocWeird, I'll check it out.